# Form not being validated by parsleyjs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The problem: parsleyjs is not validating my form. I've come to this conclusion because `$('#contact-form').parsley( 'isValid' )` returns true, when I'd expect it to return false. For example, I've set `parsley-required="true"` on all my fields, but when the form is submitted with all fields blank, it successfully submits instead of triggering a validation message.

FYI I'm also using Bootstrap in this project.

Here's the form HTML:

```
    <form method="post" id="contact-form" parsley-validate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" parsley-required="true" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-email">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="Email" parsley-required="true" parsley-type="email" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-message">Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="contact-message" placeholder="Message" parsley-required="true" name="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="Reset" id="contact-reset">
                        </div>
</form>
```

And the javascript, which is placed above the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="survey/Parsley.js-1.1.18/parsley.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( $('#contact-form').parsley( 'isValid' )) {
                $.post( "mail.php", {
                    name: $('#contact-name').val(),
                    email: $('#contact-email').val(),
                    message: $('#contact-message').val()
                }).done(function( data ) {
                            $( '#contact-form' ).parsley( 'destroy' );
                            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                            alert( "Message successfully sent.");
                        });
                return true;
            } else return false;
        });

        $('#contact-reset').click(function () {
            $( '#contact-form' ).parsley( 'destroy' );
        });

    });

</script>
```

I've tried using `required` instead of `parsley-required="true"` as the attribute for the input tags (suggested for HTML5). No difference. I've also tried other types of constraints and they don't work either.

There aren't any errors being given and I'm pretty sure the script is loading correctly since `$('#contact-form').parsley( 'isValid' )` returns a value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated parsley to 1.2.2 (I was using 1.1.18 in the code in the question) and now it works.